# Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.7.607, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource with name 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am receiving above error. I tried editing Assembly info.cs and Master pages but none helps.

In Assembly info.cs I tried

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("jquery", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("IFS.global.plugins.jQuery.jQuery-2.1.4.min.js", "text/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

In MasterPage I tried below

```
 <aspajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Name="IFS.global.plugins.jQuery.jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"/>
  </Scripts>
 </aspajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

None helps.Kindly assist